# Validating a nested model in Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

Consider this example of a nested model in Pydantic:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.class_validators import root_validator

class CarList(BaseModel):
    cars: List[str]
    colors: List[str]

class CarDealership(BaseModel):
    name: str
    cars: CarList

    @root_validator()
    def check_length(cls, v):
        cars_list = v.get("cars")

        if len(cars_list.cars) != len(cars_list.colors):
            raise ValueError("wrong length")
        
        return v


car_deal = {
    "cars": {
        "cars1": ["toyota", "tesla"], 
        "colors": ["white", "red"]
    }
}

CarDealership.parse_obj(car_deal)
```

Note that I give the wrong field name to the inner model.

I expected that the outer root validator could only be called if the inner model is valid.

However, I get this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 17, in check_length
    if len(cars_list.cars) != len(cars_list.colors):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cars'
```

I was expecting something like this instead:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CarList
cars
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

How can I make sure the inner model is validated first?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `root_validator` is called, even if other validators failed before. The idea of pydantic in this case is to collect all errors and  not raise an error on first one.

The solution is to set `skip_on_failure=True` in the `root_validator`. As a result, the `root_validator` is only called if the other fields and the submodel are valid.

With this change you will get the following error message:

```py
ValidationError: 2 validation errors for CarDealership
name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
cars -> cars
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If you change the dict to for example the following:

```py
car_deal = {
    "name": "Billy",
    "cars": {
        "cars": ["toyota", "tesla", "vw"], 
        "colors": ["white", "red"]
    }
}
```

The `root_validator` is now called and we will receive the expected error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for CarDealership
__root__
  wrong length (type=value_error)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 (almost 2024), by using the version 2.x of Pydantic and Pydantic-Settings (remember to install it), you can just do the following:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

class CarList(BaseModel):
    cars: List[str]
    colors: List[str]

class CarDealership(BaseModel):
    name: str
    cars: CarList

    @root_validator
    def check_length(cls, v):
        cars_list = v.get("cars")

        if len(cars_list.cars) != len(cars_list.colors):
            raise ValueError("wrong length")
        
        return v
```

You can also eventually give it a default value!
Note that PeopleInfo (the sub-class) is inheriting from `BaseModel` instead ClassInfo is inheriting from `BaseSettings`.

Furthermore, remember that every field must be annotated (using the type annotation)

Comment: The question was specifically about having a `root_validator` on the outer model. It's better if your example code _actually_ matches the sample classes in the question, so that it's clearer how your answer deals with the `root_validator`.

Comment: Good point, I updated the answer matching the question's classes

Answer (score -1):

Update:validation on the outer class version

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.class_validators import root_validator


class CarList(BaseModel):
    cars: List[str]
    colors: List[str]


class CarDealership(BaseModel):
    name: str
    cars_list: CarList

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def check_length(cls, v):
        cars_list = v.get("cars_list")

        if not cars_list:
            return v
        cars = cars_list.get("cars")
        colors = cars_list.get("colors")
        if not isinstance(cars, list) or not isinstance(colors, list):
            return v
        if cars is not None and colors is not None and len(cars) != len(colors):
            raise ValueError("wrong length")

        return v
```

---

The `root_validator` default `pre=False`,the inner model has already validated,so you got `v == {}`.

You can make `check_length` in `CarList`,and check whether `cars` and `colors` are exist(they has has already validated, if failed will be None).

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.class_validators import root_validator


class CarList(BaseModel):
    cars: List[str]
    colors: List[str]

    @root_validator
    def check_length(cls, v):
        cars = v.get("cars")
        colors = v.get("colors")

        if cars is not None and colors is not None and len(cars) != len(colors):
            raise ValueError("wrong length")

        return v


class CarDealership(BaseModel):
    name: str
    car_list: CarList


car_deal_1 = {
    "name": "value",
    "car_list": {
        "cars1": ["toyota", "tesla"],
        "colors": ["white", "red"]
    }
}

CarDealership.parse_obj(car_deal_1)
# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CarDealership
# car_list -> cars
#   field required (type=value_error.missing)

car_deal_2 = {
    "name": "value",
    "car_list": {
        "cars": ["toyota", "tesla"],
        "colors": ["white", "red", "bule"]
    }
}

CarDealership.parse_obj(car_deal_2)
# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CarDealership
# car_list -> __root__
#   wrong length (type=value_error)
```

Comment: The problem is I want to make that validation on the outer class since I want to use the inner class for other purposes that do not require this validation.

Answer (score -1):

Based on @YeJun response, but assuming your comment to the response that you need to use the inner class for other purposes, you can create an intermediate class with the validation while keeping the original CarList class for other uses:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.class_validators import root_validator


class CarList(BaseModel):
    cars: List[str]
    colors: List[str]


# this class will have the same fields from CarList, but with validation
class CarListWithValidator(CarList):
    @root_validator
    def check_length(cls, v):
        cars = v.get("cars")
        colors = v.get("colors")

        if cars is not None and colors is not None and len(cars) != len(colors):
            raise ValueError("wrong length")

        return v


class CarDealership(BaseModel):
    name: str
    car_list: CarListWithValidator


car_deal_2 = {
    "name": "value",
    "car_list": {
        "cars": ["toyota", "tesla"],
        "colors": ["white", "red", "bule"]
    }
}

CarDealership.parse_obj(car_deal_2)
# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CarDealership
# car_list -> __root__
#   wrong length (type=value_error)
```